# Displaying a button inside a video view

Tags: android-studio, android-xml, android-button, android-videoview

How will I display a button inside a video view with the android studio? The button seems to be there but not visible.

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <VideoView 
        android:id="@+id/vV"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:text="btn"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want the button to appear visible in the video view. The button is clickable but not visible

Answer (score 0):

Use Constrain layout by adding

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

to your gradle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorbackground">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.8" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use this inside button:

```
android:background="#00DAEDCC"
```

this will make your button transparent. I think, it will help you.